# Dual boot Mint on a Surface Pro 3?

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot

I have a shiny new SP3 and I'd like to dual boot Mint 17 on it.  I'm familiar with creating a dual boot system in general, but since the SP3 is a UEFI device, I'm a bit gun shy in this particular instance.

I found [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu) at askubuntu, but I'm not sure if they're still relevant, or if there are any differences between Ubuntu and Mint I should be aware of.

So, I basically just want to know:

1. Are the instructions I linked to above sufficient?
2. If not, what different/additional steps I should take?

Comment: Looking at the steps in that answer it seems reasonable to me that they should work for Mint as well. The install dialogs might be slightly different, but I would expect it to still be manageable.

Comment: Okay, cool.  I'll leave this question up for a few more days, and if no one else adds anything, I'll ask you to turn your comment into an answer so I can up vote and select it.

Comment: Related (Surface Pro 2): http://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu/

Comment: You can disable UEFI, and, like he said, once you got into the bios it's a peice of cake. I'd recommend that you wait till Fedora 22 or GNOME 3.12 comes out(on Arch or Gentoo) because it will have multitouch capabilities.

Comment: Eh, I don't see myself using touch with the linux side of things.  I'm comfortable with Mint since it's pretty much rock solid without requiring a lot of fiddling.  I just need a stable linux environment to do some web development on.  Mint + dotdeb has done the trick for me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found [this](http://www.geek.com/microsoft/linux-users-rejoice-heres-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-3-1594864/) (for another resource).  It tells you how to access the bios on the device.  It uses [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable usb device.  Just change the distro from Ubuntu to Mint. Checking around I found that people have installed other distros on it, including Arch,

If you are familiar with dual booting then there should be no problem once you have gotten into the bios.

**Words of caution**

You may want to check if Mint supports touch devices.  And if it is supported on the SP3.